# GLSL colormap/lookup table

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm quite new to GLSL and I am trying to apply a colormap in a fragment shader, i.e., I have some float value normalized from [0, ...., 1] and I want to convert it into an RGBA value given by a predefined map/lookup table/colormap.

I am doing this by passing a `GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB` texture, which is a single float per pixel matrix with my values and size 'width*height' . Also, I am passing a GL_RGBA32F_ARB matrix (4 floats per pixel) with the rgb values mapped from 0 to 1.

This is how I am trying to access my colormap in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler1D cmap;
...
vec4  cmapColor = texture1D(cmap, lum);
gl_FragColor = cmapColor;
```

where 'lum' is a float in the range (0, 1). However, this is failing. Am I fetching the data correctly? Is this how I get a vec4 of floats?

Comment: Usually, if you pallet, you'd want to use unsigned ints. You can use floats to look up colors, but they're going to blur together from sampling; I'm not sure what that is going to accomplish, since if they are close enough the blurring is alright, you'd probably be better off just using a signed normalized 8 bit per channel. Basically, the way you're describing this sounds like a really roundabout way to get a normalized 8 bit.

Comment: "*single float per pixel matrix*" "*GL_RGBA32F_ARB matrix*" The term you're looking for is "image format", not "matrix".